# how to re creation ios developer certification

Tags: xcode, csr

I am a develper of ios app.
then, I think that my developer csr is expired yesterday.

any one please tell me about re-rectation of developer license of apple.

thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open "Keychain Access" on your OSX, when it has opened you should click "Keychain Access" in the top left corner of your screen and then a menu pops up. Hover over "Certificate Assistant" and click "Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority...". You will now open a box that you need to fill in some info like Email and name. Fill in your email in the first and your name in the second, leave the third with nothing in it, click "Save to disk" then continue and save it to desktop or somewhere you will remember. ( DO NOT RENAME ). It will now create the certificate.

Log in to developer.apple.com and go to: https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action
Now click certificates and in development tab, click "Request Certificate" now scroll down a little and click "Chose File". (Find the file you just made in keychain access) Click "Submit" when you have chosen/uploaded the file.

Download your new certificate from the "profile" that you made on the website and "run" it.
There should now be a new certificate in keychain access.

If you have any problem with doing this, ask me for further instructions :)